# Nlog expression on existence of session object

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I added the NLog.Web NUGet package to my web project (The packages contain targets and layout-renderers specific to ASP.NET (Core), MVC and IIS).

Now I want to log, on one line:

- If session variable x exists, then log its contents.
- Else log a "Not available".

I was thinking in this direction, but it does not work:

```
${whenEmpty:whenEmpty=${aspnet-session:x}:inner=Not available:else=${aspnet-session:x}}
```

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's simpler than expected:

```
${aspnet-session:x:whenEmpty=Not available}
```